# typeorm: relation 'xxxx' does not exist

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

this is the table structure I have, a many to many relationship

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS destinations.destination
(
    destinationid integer NOT NULL,
    geolocation json,
    CONSTRAINT pk_destination PRIMARY KEY (destinationid)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS destinations.tag
(
    tagid integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    code character varying(2) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tag PRIMARY KEY (tagid)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS destinations.destination_tag
(
    destinationid integer NOT NULL,
    tagid integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_destination_tag PRIMARY KEY (destinationid, tagid),
    CONSTRAINT fk_dest_tag_dest FOREIGN KEY (destinationid)
        REFERENCES destinations.destination (destinationid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_dest_tag_tag FOREIGN KEY (tagid)
        REFERENCES destinations.tag (tagid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

that is, a destination and tag has a many to many relationship. I created the following classes in TypeORM with Tag holding destinations and Destinations holding tags

```
@Entity({ name: 'tag' })
export class Tag {

  @Column({ name: 'tagid', type: 'integer' })
  @PrimaryColumn({ primaryKeyConstraintName: 'pk_tag' })
  tagid: number

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50 })
  name: string

  @Column({ type: 'char', length: 2 })
  code: string

   

  @ManyToMany(() => Destination, d => d.tags)
  @JoinTable({
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'destinationid'
      ,referencedColumnName: 'destinationid'
      ,foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dest_tag_dest'
    },
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'tagid'
      ,referencedColumnName: 'tagid'
      ,foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dest_tag_tag'
    }
  })
  destinations: Destination[]
}


@Entity({ name: 'destination' })
export class Destination {

  @Column({ name: 'destinationid', type: 'integer' })
  @PrimaryColumn({ primaryKeyConstraintName: 'pk_destination' })
  destinationid: number

  @Column({ name: 'geolocation', type: 'integer' })
  geolocation: GeoLocation


  @ManyToMany(() => Tag,  t => t.destinations)
  @JoinTable({
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'destinationid'
      , referencedColumnName: 'destinationid'
      , foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dest_tag_dest'
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'tagid'
      , referencedColumnName: 'tagid'
      , foreignKeyConstraintName: 'fk_dest_tag_tag'
    }
  })
  tags: Tag[]
}
```

When I run the following query. I get the error:

```
   const row = await rep.findOne({
      relations: ["contents", "tags"],
      where: {
        destinationid: id
      }
    })
```

error: error: relation "destinations.destination_tags_tag" does not exist

This is the sql generated.

> query failed: SELECT DISTINCT
> "distinctAlias"."Destination_destinationid" AS
> "ids_Destination_destinationid" FROM (SELECT
> "Destination"."destinationid" AS "Destination_destinationid",
> "Destination"."geolocation" AS "Destination_geolocation",
> "Destination__Destination_tags"."tagid" AS
> "Destination__Destination_tags_tagid",
> "Destination__Destination_tags"."name" AS
> "Destination__Destination_tags_name",
> "Destination__Destination_tags"."code" AS
> "Destination__Destination_tags_code" FROM "destinations"."destination"
> "Destination"  LEFT JOIN "destinations"."**destination_tags_tag**"
> "Destination_Destination__Destination_tags" ON
> "Destination_Destination__Destination_tags"."destinationid"="Destination"."destinationid"
> LEFT JOIN "destinations"."tag" "Destination__Destination_tags" ON
> "Destination__Destination_tags"."tagid"="Destination_Destination__Destination_tags"."tagid"
> WHERE ("Destination"."destinationid" = $1)) "distinctAlias" ORDER BY
> "Destination_destinationid" ASC LIMIT 1 -- PARAMETERS: ["12"]

Where does the destination_tags_tag come from? why it doesnt use destination_tags which is the actual table?

Comment: fixed the issue by specifying the table name in the @JoinTable({ name: 'destination_tag', ...})